# Displaying full path of filename in tabs ~ Netbeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.8

I can't seem to find a way in the options to display the full path of the file at the title of the tab. I can hover over it to see it, but it would be nice to see it at a glance.

There is a SU question about it also, https://superuser.com/questions/88637/netbeans-how-to-view-file-full-path-in-window-title-or-somewhere-else

Does anyone have a solution for this to actually display it? I can see there is a custom `.jar` for it in the RC2 Netbeans, but that's probably way old now.

PS, I should mention that a path relative to the project would be ideal, as well as a full path. Either really :)

Comment: I guess this isn't possible :*(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also 'Select in --> [Project|Files|Favorites].  This opens the exposes the node for the file in the Projects, Files or Favorites explorer.

To do this, right click in the text editor for the file you are interested in; the 'Select in' item is near the bottom of the menu that appears.

Answer (score 6):

**NetBeans 8.0.2**

Tools > Options > Appearance > Document Tabs > **Show full file path**

[image]

The **full path** will appear only for the **active tab** (under the tabs), but you can also check "Show parent folder name in tab title" if you want to see the parent folder for every tab:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Try to use following [netbeans plugin](http://code.google.com/p/show-path-in-title-netbeans-module/).

Comment: This is a duplicate of @Magento solution

Answer (score 3):

In Netbeans 6.9.1 (at least) you can open the Window/Properties window and pin it under the editor; this will contain the full path in the "All Files" property which is then visible at all times and always contains the current editor file's properties.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from NetBeans 6.9 you can use the NetBeans extention "show path in title":

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42000/show-path-in-title

it's very helpful :D

Comment: The plugin is only available for NetBeans 6.9, 7.0, 7.1, and 7.2.

Comment: The questioner specifically asked for NetBeans 6.8.  This plugin states compatibility with 6.9 and newer only.

Comment: I've updated the reply with these comments, most users looking for this (like me) will simply upgrade to the latest NetBeans version

Answer (score 0):

Try using CTRL+TAB, you can find the path in status bar. This is not complete solution for your question but using keyboard (without using mouse atleast) you can find the path of the open file(s).