# Netbeans file tab features

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

In Visual Studio I used two features very much. These are `Copy full path` and `Open containing folder`. Both are very useful for me for several reasons.

Do you know any NetBeans plugins that provide these or similar functions (primarily on Windows)?

UPDATE:
There is a feature request in the NetBeans bugzilla since 2009-09-01 (not by me):
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=171222

Comment: I have similar question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864445/displaying-full-path-of-filename-in-tabs-netbeans-6-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to copy the full path you have to go to the "Projects" or "Files" tree, select the file, right mouse click -> Properties and copy the value from "All Files".

I don't think there is a built-in solution for "Open containing folder".

There exists a [Path Tools](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=676) Plugin which does exaclty what you want

- Copy Paths Action - Copy the full paths of the files/folder of selected node to the clipboard.
- Explore Action Launch the OS File Explorer (such as Windows Explorer or Finder or Koquerer or Nautilus) with the path of the file or folder of selected node selected in it.

It seems that this Plugin is no longer maintained, but I have tried it with Netbeans 6.9.1 and it's working. It even supports "Shell On Path".

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your question is that you want to open a Windows Explorer in the folder of the file you are editing.

I'm not aware of this functionality in NetBeans or a plugin that provides this. I never found myself in need for this functionality and maybe most NetBeans users feel the same. Which could explain why it's never implemented.

On the other hand, when you are editing a file you can navigate to the file in the Project Explorer View, the Files View and the Favorites View with keyboard shortcuts ctrl+1, ctrl+2, and ctrl+3 respectively.

Hope this helps.